Are water hammer arresters necessary if you have a shower with volume control?
I see a lot of videos were are installing waterhammer, arrestors in new showers. I thought they were for things like washing machine or dishwasher. My shower valve has volume control. Do I need them?

Do you get bangs when turning off the shower?
